# "This Question Belongs to Another Stack Exchange Network". Como sinalizar para o SO?

Tags: suporte, sinalização

[Fui sinalizar uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21714/how-do-i-solve-this-notice-undefined-index-submit-in-c-wamp-www-mezzo-com-re) e não consigo indicar no motivo que esta pergunta pertence ao Stack Overflow.

Como fazer?

Comment: [Pergunta relacionada](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1031/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-em-um-outro-idioma). A resposta do Gabe indica o que fazer nesses casos. Sinalizar é uma opção, mas nesse caso está claro pelo contexto que o OP fala português. Mas para referência futura, creio que a opção aplicável nessa situação é "outro (precisa da ♦ atenção do moderador)" (me corrijam se eu estiver enganado).

Comment: O que afinal de contas significa OP? =P

Comment: @mgibsonbr Acho que são duas coisas diferentes. O Gabe falou em não ter o recurso de migrar, mas o que eu me refiro é em poder sinalizar. Pelo menos isso deveria ser possível.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Sim, eu entendi, por isso pus "pergunta relacionada" e não "duplicata". A pergunta é válida, coloquei o que eu acredito ser a ação correta no comentário, mas preferi não colocar como resposta porque eu não tenho certeza.

Comment: @TremDoido [*Original Poster*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=op). Algumas pessoas já sugeriram AP - Autor da Postagem - mas eu particularmente não sou muito fã não... :P

Comment: Ou "Autor da Pergunta", não?

Comment: @mgibsonbr "precisa da ♦ atenção do moderador" é bug de tradução hein...

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez É que às vezes se usa OP para o "AR" também :)

Comment: @bfavaretto hehe foi copiado e colado direto do diálogo de sinalização. Depois procuro se alguém já reportou esse bug (já estourei minha cota de SOpt por hoje) e - se não - podemos fazê-lo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O procedimento é sinalizar como "outro" e informar o site no campo de detalhes.

O problema é da ferramenta de sinalização: ela na verdade implementa a migração por esse caminho:

```
fechar > descontextualizada > pertence a outro site > [site]
```

Moderadores vêem um campo para especificar o site e disparar a migração. No SO em inglês, existem algumas opções pré-definidas visíveis para usuários com reputação para fechar, e se a pergunta for fechada por esse motivo ela acaba migrada (acho que precisa haver unanimidade, ou quase, em relação ao destino).

Então eu não consideraria isso um bug, mas pode virar um pedido de [novo-recurso](/questions/tagged/novo-recurso) para que a comunidade possa migrar sozinha para o SO. Se bem que eu acho que o pedido acabaria negado, pois existe uma grande resistência contra migrações na rede.

Comment: Perfeito. Vou até fazer um retagging para que vire um novo recurso.

Comment: Você quer mesmo a migração direta via comunidade, ou **[isto](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1513/sugest%C3%B5es-de-frase-pronta-para-fechamento-de-perguntas-em-outros-idiomas)** resolveria?

Comment: Mais ou menos isto.

Comment: Então não seria duplicata nem da [minha pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1513/sugest%C3%B5es-de-frase-pronta-para-fechamento-de-perguntas-em-outros-idiomas) nem da [pergunta do Bacco](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1241/podemos-ter-op%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-migra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-o-soz%C3%A3o)? Mas quase?